# Outlook - mailitem.copy is it possible to save a instance of the mail in the memory

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, outlook-addin

When I use mailItem2=mailItem.copy(); it creates a copy of mailitem in the inbox.
I would like to ask if it is possible to create an instance of mailitem in memory without creating a copy in the Inbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A message cannot exist without a parent store or at least an MSG file.

Is saving the message as an MSG file an option? What exactly are you doing and why?

Comment: I have a mail item which will have it's contents edited when i open to view the mail. 

When i close it , i'll get the prompt of "attachments/contents of the message has been changed, do you want to save it ?"

i'm trying to bypass this prompt by replacing the mailitem with it's original untouched copy when i close the mailitem.

I understand that I can close the mailitem using the method mailitem.close(discard) but i can't make it work in the close event of the mailitem. 

You once suggested me to use a timer but my team wanted me to avoid using a timer. so i'm at a loss at what to do.

Comment: mailitem.close(discard) is the only way to discard the changes without a prompt, I don't think there is any other way. What is wrong with using a timer?

Answer (score 0):

Just declare another MailItem variable and set it:

```
mailItem2 = mailtem;
```